# Creating (and editing) rectangles with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to create multiple rectangles in my page, but I need to be able to edit their properties later on (color and position).

My html have:

```
<div id="display-area">
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
</div>
```

and my external javascript:

```
function drawRectangles() {

    var i;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    /* Set the size of canvas */
    document.getElementById('myCanvas').setAttribute('width', '600');
    document.getElementById('myCanvas').setAttribute('height', '500');

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";

    /* Creates 50 rectangles in random positions and colors */
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 550) + 1);
        y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 1);

        context.fillStyle = getRandomColor();

        context.strokeRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

I need to access these rectangles, but I'm only able to access the canvas. Is there any way or should I try a different implementation to have access to them?

Comment: If you want to access the rectangles, you may try SVG instead of canvas.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the rectangles?

Comment: you can't access the 'retangles' becouse you don't have them. cavans is like a paper where you draw on it. The retangles are not objects. What you can do is keep in some object (like an array) the coordinates of the retangles and their colors. With this datas you gonna be able to redraw a specific retangle.

Comment: silly question: why are you using the canvas for this? Why not just make 50 rectangular divs with absolute positioning on your page instead? Give each div a click handler, done. Now you won't even have to write the code for figuring out which click where selects which div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to keep track of all your rectangles, instead of just drawing random rectangles and then forgetting about them.  Once the rectangles are drawn on the canvas, the canvas contains now knowledge of them anymore, only the pixels that resulted.

```
var rectangleList = [];
/* Creates 50 rectangles in random positions and colors */
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 550) + 1);
    y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 450) + 1);
    var color = getRandomColor();

    // Save the rectangle in a list for later.
    rectangleList.push({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      color: color,
    });

    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.strokeRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

Once you have a list of all the rectangles, any time you change one, you will need to re-render the canvas to update it.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";

for (i = 0; i < rectangleList.length; i++) {

    // Iterate through each of the previously remembered rectangles, then re-draw them.
    x = rectangleList[i].x;
    y = rectangleList[i].y;
    var color = rectangleList[i].color;

    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.strokeRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```